# Download center using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am developing an app that enable user to download books, when user start download he still at the screen (Modal Screen) till the download finish, but if it's a large book? it will be a problem so I want user to close the screen but monitor the download progress from SlidingMenu or ViewController also if they are multiple files can monitor their progress also, I am using this code to download the file in the same screen.

```
NSString *pathURL=item.path;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathURL]];
    operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:item.fileName];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    mbProcess.progress=(float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        _loadinglabel.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Downloading %d %",(int)(100*((float)totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead))];
    _progressDialogdet.progress=(float)totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    }];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         //   [mbProcess removeFromSuperview];


}];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: Don't mix your view code with your networking code! Have a separate object that downloads an manages networks. Interested view controllers can ask it for current downloads and progress reports if they're interested.

Comment: Actually I don't mix them but it's about managing between them. let's say there's a class responsible for downloading and we need to control it from other controller.